# How to use the data from csv file to Matplotlib Bar Chart in jupyter

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib

Could someone help me with how to create a bar graph in python using a CSV file? I want to plot a bar graph with the x-axis as ReleaseMonth and the y-axis with Rating, which I can interpret which month has the highest rating from the bar graph.

Below is my data head:

[image]

Comment: Check here for more info https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html

Answer (score 0):

```
import seaborn as sns

ax = sns.barplot(x="ReleaseMonth", y="Rating", data=df)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your code, and it won't work. Could you help me with other codes and provide some explanation. Thanks so much for your time. I will appreciate it.

Comment: What is the output you are getting? You can check seaborn's bar plot here: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html

Comment: I couldn't understand much from the link that you shared.

Comment: # importing the libraries that we'll need
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

#reading the file
df=pd.read_csv(r'imdb_superhero.csv')
df=pd.DataFrame(df)

  
# Plot the data using bar() method
plt.bar(X=df['ReleaseMonth'], Y=df['Rating'])
plt.title('ReleaseMonth Vs Rating')
plt.xlabel("ReleasMonth")
plt.ylabel("Ratings")
  
# Show the plot
plt.show()

Comment: I am using matplot, it tells me TypeError: bar() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'x' and 'height'. Could you help me why my codes are wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
x_release_month = df["ReleaseMonth"]
y_rating = df["Rating"]

# setting the size of the figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))

#bar plot
plt.bar(x_release_month, y_rating)
plt.show()
```